# When I try to replace a file in the server, it says it is not possible because another application has opened the folder or one of its files

Tags: windows

I have a server running windows server 2022 21h2.

I have an Excel file .xlsm (an Excel file with macros, but I don't know if this is important).

When I copy to a folder in the server and then I try to copy again, it prompts to replace the file. I choose yes. It tries to copy it, but it tells that is not possible to replace the file because another application has opened the folder or one of its files. Close the folder or the file and retry.

I have to delete the file and copy it again. Then it is copied.

I have tried with anothers files, .pdf, .doc, .txt and this problem doesn't happen, I can replace the file.

I have tried restarting the computer, to avoid any application opens the file, and the problem persists.

Also I have try from another computer, and the problem is the same. So it seems a problem in the server.

So I don't know why I have problems with this file, and not with anothers.

Thanks.

Comment: What is (or are) the security software installed in the server ?

Comment: This has happened to me if moving a file from a secured location to a non-secured location (Windows Defender is the only AV).  I have not determined what precisely causes this. I move the source file to a non secured location and then I can move it.

Comment: I am still looking.  Sometimes copying a file works where moving a file (same time, source, target) does not work.

Comment: @harrymc the swciruty software is windows defender and windows fireall. I don't have third party security applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool, such as [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/lockhunter/) to see what is locking the file.

[image: LockHunter]

It could be the file is open for indexing, for a malware scan, or some other process has an open handle to it.

Comment: But this won't work if the server side has locked it.  This will only show open handles from the local machine.  It is indeed worth a shot though since the probability of it being AV or a shell extension is very high.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I was thinking about the AV in the server side. But if it is because of the AV, I am wondering why it let it to copy the file but not replace it? If the file is detected as possible threat, it shouldn't let it copy neither replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The user account you're using, or the share permissions, seem to not
include the Modify permission on the folder, which is required for
overwriting/changing existing files.

It does seem to have the Write permission, which permits to add new
files to the folder, and it also has the Delete permission.

Check both the permissions on the share and in the file-system.
It's enough that one of these two separate sets of permissions
does not include the Modify permission, to block the overwrite
operation.

Comment: In the folder, the user has permissions to modify, read, run, write, and red. In fact, this only happens with certain files. I have tried with other Excel, .doc, .txt, and .pdf files, and I don’t have this problem. I think that perhaps this Excel file (which has VBA code) has something in particular that is causing this behavior.

Comment: Did you also check the permissions of the share  ?

Comment: I have checked and the user has both, change and read.

Comment: I would suggest to add to your post screenshots of the permissions of the folder and the share, because I don't see another explanation. You could of course temporarily disable the antivirus on the server to see if it's the problem.